Are there any other opinions on 6 constant mitzvas
Sefer hachinuch seems to have introduced the idea of 6 constant mitzvas.
Some are debatable.  For example - dont go after your heart.  Sometimes your heart is full of good stuff that should be followed.
There are other opinions on the Rambams 13 principals.  For example some say 4 or 1 principals etc
Do any rishonim or commentators disagree with 6 constant mitzvas and have a different number?

ולא תתורו אחרי לבבכם is a pasuk, not Sefer Hachinuch's opinion. Of course, it doesn't just mean "don't go after your heart"

It is one of the 6 mitzvot listed in the sefer chinuk's list of 6 constant mitzvas.  Are you suggesting he made up all the mitzvas without a source?  What are you talking about?  The question is are there other opinions on how many constant mitzvot there are.  I dont understand what you are adding.

Have you read the Chinuch on this mitzvah? "The content of this negative commandment is that we were prevented from dedicating our thoughts to think about opinions that are antithetical to the ones on which the Torah is built, as that may lead one to apostasy. Rather, if the spirit to pursue these bad opinions should arise, one should minimize his thinking about them, and redouble his efforts to contemplate the true and good ways of the Torah. Similarly, one should not pursue the things he sees; and included in this is that we not pursue after the desires of this world

I dont get your point.  I said " Some are debatable"  You are saying its not debatable?  Are you saying there is only one definition of every mitzva and its exactly like the Chinuch?  I asked does anyone bring a different number.  You seem to be saying every mitzva can be turned into a constant mitzva - Minimize thinking about murder.   " if the spirit to pursue these bad opinions should arise" Would mean that if the spirit doesnt arise then it is not a constant.    Did you understand the question?

Maybe I don't understand the question, perhaps you could make it clearer

Thinking about murder is not prohibited by the Torah

Do any rishonim or commentators disagree with 6 constant mitzvas and have a different number?
